# Pass input text to initial set date for date picker

Tags: javascript, html, datepicker

I want to be able to set the initial date for the JavaScript date picker widget I'm using by taking the value from the input field.

The input field is accepting values of "YYYY-MM-DD", would like this value passed to the date picker I'm using and to pop up with the date.

```
<input id="date" type="text" name="date" placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD" />
```

...

```
$A.bind(window, 'load', function(){
    // Syntax : setCalendar( ID , TriggeringElement , TargetEditField , EnableComments , clickHandler , config )
$A.setCalendar('UniqueCalendarId', $A.getEl('dateIcon'), $A.getEl('date'), false, undefined, {
    // Allow a date that isn't today to be set as the initial date. If unset, this value is initialized to today's date
    initialDate: new Date(),
});
```

Comment: You want to set a fixed date and not allow someone to choose the date? Not sure I'm understanding the question. Why use a "datepicker" for a static date?

Comment: Also, in HTML5 you can try the input type="date" where you won't need JS to handle the date-picker. Does not work with IE 11 and earlier, but globally accepted otherwise.

Comment: Sorry, should have been clearer. I want to pass the value that's in the input field to the date picker so when it initially pops up it'll be set to that date, the user can still click another date and it'll replace what was once in the input field.
Currently whats happening is, if the input field has a date in it (example 2015-06-05) when i open the datepicker it's initial date will be the current date (2018-06-06)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to grab the current date as part of a "date-picker" process, I would go with the HTML5:

```
<input id="date" type="date">
```

Which can be demonstrated here:

```html
<form>
<input id="date" type="date">
</form>
```

Even though older browsers don't support this feature, I believe it's limited to IE only at this point. And it gracefully degrades to type="text" on non-supporting browsers, but then, the date will have to manually be entered.

Alternatively, MDN provides some great examples here of how to integrate with JS as a fallback for the HTML input type. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date

If you absolutely want to stay "scripty", I recommend [jQuery datepicker UI](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/).

Where you could perform the same task as such:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  } );
  </script>
</head>
<body>
 
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
 
 
</body>
</html>
```

Give it a shot.